# Identifier "cusparseXXX" is undefined on cuda11

Tags: cuda, cudnn

I'm building a package tested for CUDA 9,10 from source, trying to compile it for CUDA11.

I've already changed `gencode=arch=compute_70` (was set on 30), and added

```
target_link_libraries(tsnecuda ${CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY})
```

Unfortunately, I still get

```
tsne-cuda/src/util/math_utils.cu(153): error: identifier "cusparseScsr2csc" is undefined

tsne-cuda/src/util/math_utils.cu(165): error: identifier "cusparseXcsrgeamNnz" is undefined

tsne-cuda/src/util/math_utils.cu(195): error: identifier "cusparseScsrgeam" is undefined

3 errors detected in the compilation of "tsne-cuda/src/util/math_utils.cu".
CMake Error at tsnecuda_generated_math_utils.cu.o.cmake:276 (message):
  Error generating file
  tsne-cuda/build/CMakeFiles/tsnecuda.dir/src/util/./tsnecuda_generated_math_utils.cu.o
```

Is there a chance the build process somehow ignores my `target_link_libraries`? Should I add something else?

Answer (score 1):

Undefined identifier is a compilation issue, not a linking issue.

At least part of the problem here is that CUDA deprecated and removed some functionality from cusparse, including `cusparse<t>csr2csc()`.  The code would need to be rewritten to compile correctly under the latest versions of CUDA 11.x.

For example, for csr2csc, the call to `cusparseScsr2csc` might be refactored to use [this  function](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#csr2cscEx2) instead.

One example of deprecation/removal notice for `cusparse<t>csr2csc` is given [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.2/cusparse/index.html#csr2csc).